# An issue with HAPROXY on sll that give error verify return code: 20

Tags: amazon-web-services, haproxy, openssl

I have an issue with HAProxy config on AWS.

The issue is when I make requests over SSL it triggers two types of errors:

1. When I go to https it gives this following error: "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port"
2. When I do a cli command such `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443` I get this response:

---

```
subject=/serialNumber=XX/OU=GT98690993/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps  (c)13/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=*.dev.qmerce.com issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
--- No client certificate CA names sent
--- SSL handshake has read 3031 bytes and written 415 bytes
--- New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA Server public key is 2048 bit Secure Renegotiation IS supported Compression: NONE Expansion: NONE SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
    Session-ID: 76AC086D608DCB4B02918B4DEDE6CD3223D4723B849CF2A896B7FA6C94382958
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: CDA7D024B220290F162D9A591503D1503049E87C3A9A38475908DD3756DB45E1107430B1B164EA1D059023125D62E61C
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - de 78 c0 f7 cf 25 47 30-fe ec 39 34 62 45 95 fb   .x...%G0..94bE..
    0010 - 50 cb 99 d4 28 92 44 96-17 19 2d 6d c9 7f 42 4b   P...(.D...-m..BK
    0020 - a2 4c b8 e5 c6 69 ba 71-c8 cf 6d 1a 94 c8 2a 89   .L...i.q..m...*.
    0030 - 89 24 e5 81 d6 68 06 3a-8d 40 63 7c a4 87 c8 51   .$...h.:.@c|...Q
    0040 - af 8e a1 06 a9 d0 40 9f-ae d2 fd 57 27 62 80 74   ......@....W'b.t
    0050 - 96 94 ae c2 36 ee 85 20-3b 01 78 bb 20 f9 f9 34   ....6.. ;.x. ..4
    0060 - b9 f5 54 18 ad 45 89 ab-39 29 e1 56 a2 e5 e5 23   ..T..E..9).V...#
    0070 - 74 00 65 0b 2c 85 db f9-d5 5b 32 da 49 ea 06 20   t.e.,....[2.I..
    0080 - a3 ca e4 e0 05 62 85 89-de db 20 8d 2b 8f 05 b0   .....b.... .+...
    0090 - 80 05 e9 34 ab 35 93 61-4d cc c8 d0 8b b0 02 d0   ...4.5.aM.......

    Start Time: 1378712486
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
--- HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out Cache-Control: no-cache Connection: close Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1> Your browser didn't send a complete request in time. </body></html>
```

now the config file for the haproxy is this:

```
global
  log /dev/log   local0 info
  log /dev/log   local0 notice
  maxconn 4096
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  daemon
  ca-base /etc/ssl/qmerce
  crt-base /etc/ssl/qmerce

defaults
  log global
  maxconn 4096
  mode http
  option  httplog
  option  dontlognull
  # Add x-forwarded-for header.
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client 30s
  timeout server 30s
  contimeout      5000
  clitimeout      50000
  srvtimeout      50000
  # Long timeout for WebSocket connections.
  timeout tunnel 1h
  option redispatch
  retries 3
  timeout http-request 10s
  timeout queue 1m

frontend public
  # HTTP
  bind :80
  # Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
  reqadd X-Forwrded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http if !{ ssl_fc }
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
 # Example with CA certificate bundle
  # bind :443 ssl crt dev.qmerce.com.key ca-file dev.qmerce.com.crt
  # Example without CA certification bunch
  bind :443 ssl ca-file dev.qmerce.com.crt crt qmerce.pem ecdhe secp521r1 ciphers !kDHE:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH
#prefer-server-ciphers ciphers !kDHE:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH verify required

  # The node backends - websockets will be managed automatically, given the
  # right base paths to send them to the right Node.js backend.
  #
  # If you wanted to specifically send websocket traffic somewhere different
  # you'd use an ACL like { hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket }. Looking at path works
  # just as well, though - such as { path_beg /socket.io } or similar. Adjust your
  # rules to suite your specific setup.
  #use_backend node if { path_beg /served/by/node/ }
  # Everything else to Nginx.
  use_backend normal_nginx if !{ ssl_fc }
  default_backend nginx


frontend node
  bind :8000 ssl  crt qmerce.pem
  default_backend node

backend normal_nginx
  option httpchk HEAD /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0
  # Wait 500ms between checks.
  option httplog
  option forwardfor
  option httpclose
  server web1 ec2-54-243-14-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:443 cookie LSW_WEB01 check inter 500ms

backend node
  # Tell the backend that this is a secure connection,
  # even though it's getting plain HTTP.
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https

  balance leastconn
  # Check by hitting a page intended for this use.
  option httpchk HEAD /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0
  timeout check 500ms
  option ssl-hello-chk
  # Wait 500ms between checks.
  server node1 ec2-54-243-14-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000 check inter 500ms

backend nginx
  # Tell the backend that this is a secure connection,
  # even though it's getting plain HTTP.
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https

  balance roundrobin
  # Check by hitting a page intended for this use.
  option httpchk HEAD /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0
  timeout check 500ms
  cookie LSW_WEB insert indirect nocache
  option ssl-hello-chk
  option abortonclose
  stats enable
  stats hide-version
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats uri /?qmerce_lb_stats
  stats auth admin:admin
  # Wait 500ms between checks.
  server web1 ec2-54-243-14-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:443 cookie LSW_WEB01 check inter 500ms
```

Now I have no clue any more.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For #1, if your normal_nginx backend server is running https, HAProxy won't be able to connect properly; it doesn't understand https backends without some coersion. You can use stunnel to convince it to make SSL requests.

For #2, you have to pass openssl a cafile or capath for it to verify the server's certificate. The remainder of the error is not concering-- it's literally saying you didn't ask it what you wanted fast enough so it disconnected you.